# Automating 2-step Authentication with Selenium / Python?

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, google-authentication

I tried install 'Google Authentication' and 'Authy' to use 2-step verification, but the both don't give-me the TOTP key ...

The code for input the 6 digits i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870489/how-to-handle-google-authenticator-with-selenium)

I tried get all TOTP keys using [this](https://gist.github.com/gboudreau/94bb0c11a6209c82418d01a59d958c93) but i receive : 'secret=undefined'

**What i need?**
I need some method to get the 6 digits of authentication or some method to simply get the TOTP key, as I just need to implement it in the code.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this? I'm using Python + Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below simple code and check if you are providing the right secret.

```
from pyotp import *
totp = TOTP("16 chars secret code goes here")
token = totp.now()
print (token)
```

Comment: Try this out in a simple `.py` file to validate the set is correct.

Comment: but how i get the secret key ?? i don't know

Comment: Did you already configured the google authenticator on a device?

Comment: Yes, I have google authenticator on my device and it shows me the 6 digits every 30 seconds. But if google authenticator is not compatible with selenium I can switch to any other application without any problems

Comment: you can click on `Import Backup` in the google auth and get the security code from the file.

Comment: Don't have this opition in the app =\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200470/discussion-between-supputuri-and-user3602803).