# Access private github page like a browser (with Python)

Tags: python, github, web-scraping

I have a private github repo containing a README:

https://github.com/guettli/test/blob/master/README.md

I want to access this README just like a web browser does, but with a python script.

My account uses two-factor-auth.

I tried it with basic auth, like explained in the docs of requests: [basic auth (requests lib)](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/).

I get a 404 (not found).

How can I get the HTML of the README.md file?

The mark-down source does not help in my case.

The script gets executed on a server (not desktop).

Comment: If `requests` doesn't load the necessary JavaScript try using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). You can see how they did it with google two factor [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55871687/5811078).

Comment: I think it is possible to do this with `requests`,selenium is too slow to do this and it need session or cookie.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA speed does not matter at the moment. First it should work - I will optimize later (if needed).

Comment: @guettli So you can use selenium. wwwwww...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) web driver to crawl GitHub. You could either login with it and go to your repository and extract the HTML of `README.md` or save the `user_session` cookie from the browser and use it to be authenticated. Although it will expire after some time and you will need to renew it.

Comment: The script gets executed on a server (not desktop).

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can run it on a server aswell. Selenium creates a headless web driver with which you can access websites just like a normal desktop browser would.