# Python + Selenium - Microsoft 2FA

Tags: python, selenium, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to log in to Azure DevOps using Python and Selenium. I can enter the username and password just fine, but I have the Microsoft Authenticator App on my phone set to give me a prompt to "approve" or "deny" when trying to log in.

I've tried having Selenium wait until the "No" button element on the stay signed in page is present (see screenshot below),
[image]
but it doesn't seem to like it. I took a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870489/how-to-handle-google-authenticator-with-selenium) which is regarding Google's Authenticator. The solution uses Google Authenticator's secret, along with pyotp. I can't seem to find a way to get a secret from the MS Authenticator, at least for myself. I checked out [this](https://www.appypie.com/faqs/how-can-i-get-my-microsoft-acount-client-id-and-client-secret-key) guide, but I do not have access to Azure AD.

Here's the code I've tried to wait for the screen after 2FA:

```
def signin(user, passwd):
    # find elements before passing information
    username = browser.find_element_by_name('loginfmt')
    username.send_keys(user)
    username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(1)

    password = browser.find_element_by_name('passwd')
    password.send_keys(passwd)
    password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "idBtn_Back"))
        ).click()
    finally:
        sys.exit('Timeout for 2FA approval reached. Try again.')
```

Unfortunately, as I briefly mentioned above, even after stay signed in page appears, Python isn't able to detect the "No" button. I don't really care which button is used because the script is using a separate instance of the browser where I'm not signed in.

I've considered setting a long `time.sleep()` command, but that seems like a really stupid way to do it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Link to website?

Comment: @Yatin the URL is `https://<companyName>.visualstudio.com/`, but you're immediately redirected to a sign in page, such as this - `https://login.microsoftonline.com/9fdf2c7e-d190-4b8e-ba6b-2cd9be62632e/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<client_id and other sensitive information>`

Answer (score 0):

> Python isn't able to detect the "No" button.

Trust me whenever I find something weird happening in Python, something that absolutely doesn't make sense, where the program simply doesn't do what it is told, I have always found a `try-except` statement there. And that my friend is your mistake.

Also [`finally` will always execute](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_finally.asp). Doesn't matter if `try` works or fails.

```py
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "idBtn_Back"))
        ).click()
```

is simply wrong! Try running it on its own:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b43596b524d7> in <module>
      9 
     10 WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "i0116")))
---> 11 driver.find_element_by_id("i0116").send_keys("u18ec013@svnitsuratg.onmicrosoft.com").click()
     12 
     13 WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "idSIButton9")))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Because you simply can't call `.click()` on a `WebDriverWait`'s output (which is `None`).

The following code works fine:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path/to/executable')

driver.get("https://login.microsoftonline.com")

WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "i0116")))
driver.find_element_by_id("i0116").send_keys("your_emailid")

WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "idSIButton9")))
driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()

driver.find_element_by_id("i0118").send_keys("your_password")
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "idSIButton9")))
driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "idSIButton9")))
driver.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()
```

In your case, you simply need to change it to:

```
def signin(user, passwd):
    # find elements before passing information
    username = browser.find_element_by_name('loginfmt')
    username.send_keys(user)
    username.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    time.sleep(1)

    password = browser.find_element_by_name('passwd')
    password.send_keys(passwd)
    password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

    try:
        WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "idBtn_Back")))
        browser.find_element_by_id("idSIButton9").click()

    except:
        sys.exit('Timeout for 2FA approval reached. Try again.')
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me Yatin! Unfortunately the last block you sent isn't working. I'm hitting the timeout still. The console is immediately throwing the timeout error.

Comment: @Flu17 you weren't using `finally` [correctly](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_finally.asp). `finally` will **always execute**. So even if the code in `try` works `finally` will execute. See the code now

Comment: oh I see, yes that works, thank you. Just the `try` section isn't working still :(

Comment: "isn't working still" try removing the `try` part and let the code fail... that way you will be able to tell what the error is... Send me the error..